# Bash: Add inline if to modify script

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm writing a bash script where I need to do 2 different actions depending on the arguments.

For example calling my script without params (`./script`) it should do this:

`docker-compose run ...`

how ever if I send a param to my script (`./script -d`) it should do this:

`docker-compose -f file run...`

So the `-f file` is the only part added based on the argument. I dont want to repeat the whole code in each if statement, is there a better way?

Comment: If you add any parameter, or if you add specifically `-d`?  Is `file` a hard-coded string, or is it an argument to the `-d` flag?

Comment: hardcoded string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use an array. If `-d` is present then add `-f "$file"` to the array.

```
args=()
[[ $1 == -d ]] && args+=(-f "$file")
docker-compose "${args[@]}" run...
```

Another is to use `:+` to substitute an alternate value only when a variable is set. If `$option` is set to `-d` then substitute `-f "$file"`; if it's empty then leave it empty.

```
option=
[[ $1 == -d ]] && option=-d
docker-compose ${option:+-f "$file"} run...
```

Both of these options will handle file names that contain whitespace correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to handle args (including `getopts`), but most simply,

```
#!/bin/bash

# by default, set to none; otherwise, set to some value
[ "$1" = "-d" ] && args="-f file" || args=

docker-compose $args run ...
```

Comment: Do not use regular parameters to represent lists of words.

Comment: ...(extending @chepner's comment) unless you are concerned about portability and may run your script in a shell that has no support for arrays.

Comment: Even then, I don't recommend doing this. In portable shell, there is no particularly safe way to build up lists of arguments. I'd abstract away the common part to a function (e.g., `dc_run () { docker-compose "$@" run; }`), then make different calls to `dc_run` as appropriate.

Comment: arrays across bash versions can be problematic (for those not just using linux), e.g, aix, solaris, z/OS (oddly, esp. solaris). By default I keep most of my scripts free of latter-day bashisms unless it's a long/complicated script and really only intended for linux.

Comment: the OP didn't specify what `file` was, so this answer doesn't bother to speculate. Correct that using `"$@"` to properly handle expansion is a good idea (and I approve of functions, etc, etc).. but that's an exercise left to either the reader or a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to parse arguments.  A `test` (or `[[`) is the simplest approach, though if there's the possibility of multiple conditions, a `case` statement might be preferable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case "$1" in;
  -d) args=( -f "file" ) ;;
  "") args=() ;;
  *) echo "Usage error." >/dev/null; exit 1 ;;
esac

docker-compose "${args[@]}" run
```

For larger scale options handling, `getopts` is probably the way to go:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

args=()
while getopts hdf: opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    h) printf "Usage: ${0##*/} [-d]"; exit 0 ;;
    d) args=( -f "file" ) ;;       # use a static file
    f) args=( -f "$OPTARG" ) ;;    # use a user-specified file
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

docker-compose "${args[@]}" run
```

For usage information, search the "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" section for `getopts`.